# Filtering out double and triple digit numbers using php?

Tags: php, regex

The question is pretty simple.
I am not quite clear with the `regular expressions`. Can this be done using regular expressions?

If the user enters double or triple digit number, echo `This number cant be used`.
If the user enters any other number, echo `Go ahead`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$your_input = 123;
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{2,3}$/', $your_input)) { // check if its double or three digit number
    echo 'invalid input';
}
else {
    echo 'valid input'; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a regular expression.

```
if (!ctype_digit($target) || strlen($target) == 2 || strlen($target) == 3) {
    # Number is invalid
}
```

Comment: Using this approach `0x1` would be valid too. That's probably not what the OP wants. Better use `ctype_digit`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner...

```
echo strlen($yournumber)==2 || strlen($yournumber)==3 ? "Number cant be used" : "Go ahead";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!is_numeric($str) || strlen($str) == 2 || strlen($str) == 3) 
{
    echo "This number cant be used";
}
else
{
    echo "Go dhead";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(preg_match('/^\d{2,3}$/',$string)){ echo "valid";}else{echo "not valid";}
```

this will work for both conditions

```
$string = 111;
$string = "111";
```